# Declaring Markers Javascript Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-markers

ive been declaring markers like this for a wile now:

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

```
    position: myLatlng,

    map: map,

    title: 'XXXxx (xcv)'

});
```

but i need to do it another way something like this:

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

```
    position: (-25.363882,131.044922),

    map: map,

    title: 'XXXxx (xcv)'

});
```

is there any way to do this easily :)

Answer (score 2):

The position has to be a LatLng object, So if you want to do it the second way it would need to be done like this:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

    position: new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922),

    map: map,

    title: 'XXXxx (xcv)'

});
```